# Converting unsigned short* to int*

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

How can I convert `unsigned short*` to `int*` in C++?

Comment: Why would you want to do *that*? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried cast, but it did not work. The function takes int* as input, but my data type is unsigned short*, so I figure conversion is needed?

Comment: Yeah, but you'll want to convert every single item in the input... post some more of your code, so we can know what your are doing (you are asking for a "blind" answer, if we can't see it)...

Comment: Remember that a `short` and an `int` are two different types, with different sizes (in most modern architectures). So, you can't just cast one pointer as the other (yes, you can, with `reinterpret_cast`, but _that_ is probably **not what you want** to do...)

Comment: You need to specify whether you want each int to contain one short value, or more than one packed short value.

Comment: @Ono: "... but it did not work." *How* did it not work?

Comment: Just to reiterate what @Massa said, by passing a `unsigned short*` type as an `int*`, you're hoping said function won't result in an overflow error ... so why is your type an `unsigned short` and the function type an `int`? Can your `unsigned short` not be a temp `int` you then check?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the problem. I expected there is an easy way to cast unsigned short* to int*. Cast did not work as I tried, compile says the type not compatible. I guess I need to think about the problem a little more, perhaps use the same data type. Thanks to all of you, I really appreciate your help. It is really wonderful that you share your valued opinion with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
    unsigned short * p1;
    std::vector<int> vec(p1, p1 + p1_size);
    other_function(vec.data());//or &vec[0] pre C++11
```

This `std::vector` constructor is taking two pointers as begin and end iterators and it copies (and converts) to an internal buffer, later accessed with `data()`.